# Bucle for no lee un string/cadena complet@

Tags: python, string, bucle-for, bucles

El ejercicio trata de contar el numero de veces q cada palabra se repite dentro de un texto.
Sucede q el for debe pasar por cada una de las letras de la cadena, para poder discernir que es una palabra o no. Por algun motivo solo me lee hasta la penultima palabra pasando por alto la ultima.

```
texto = "Este es un texto cualquiera para realizar una prueba de reconocimiento de texto. Si hay puntos o comas, deberan ser eliminadas"
i=0
lista= []
j=""

for i in texto:#i es igual a cada uno de los elementos q tenga texto. El bucle se extenderá tanto como elementos tenga texto.
  if not i== " ":
    if not i==",":
        if not i ==".":
          j+=i
  else: 
    lista.append(j)
    j="" 

for i in range(len(lista)):
  print(f"De la palabra '{lista[i]}' existe numero de repeticiones: ", lista.count(lista[i]))

for i in range(len(lista)):
  print(lista[i], end="")
```

Esto es lo que me imprime en consola cuando pido lo que hay en "lista":

```
EsteesuntextocualquierapararealizarunapruebadereconocimientodetextoSihaypuntosocomasdeberanser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El detalle es que cuando se termina la cadena y sales del `for`, tienes una palabra en construcción (en `j`) que nunca incorporas a la lista.

**Solución**

Al salir del `for`, revisa si `j` trae algo (la última palabra) y agregalo a la lista.

```
for i in texto:#i es igual a cada uno de los elementos q tenga texto. El bucle se extenderá tanto como elementos tenga texto.
  if not i== " ":
    if not i==",":
        if not i ==".":
          j+=i
  else:
    lista.append(j)
    j=""

if j:
    lista.append(j)
```

produce

```
De la palabra 'Este' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'es' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'un' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'texto' existe numero de repeticiones:  2
De la palabra 'cualquiera' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'para' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'realizar' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'una' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'prueba' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'de' existe numero de repeticiones:  2
De la palabra 'reconocimiento' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'de' existe numero de repeticiones:  2
De la palabra 'texto' existe numero de repeticiones:  2
De la palabra 'Si' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'hay' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'puntos' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'o' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'comas' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'deberan' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'ser' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
De la palabra 'eliminadas' existe numero de repeticiones:  1
EsteesuntextocualquierapararealizarunapruebadereconocimientodetextoSihaypuntosocomasdeberansereliminadas
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue un error tonto xD